# Android Studio keeps backing up changed classes (Git)

Tags: git, android-studio

I have a question about Android Studio.

Does anybody know how to somehow disable automatic backup of classes, when such class is changed against its previous state?
By this state I mean Git commit.

So to have an example:

1. I push my commits (local and remote are in sync)
2. Then I change the class.
3. After a while (matter of minutes) the class is automatically duplicated and to the duplicate's name is date suffix appended, see:

[image: screenshot]

It can be really annoying.

To this date I was not able to find any help here in the community nor in the project/IDE settings.

I use AS 3.2 and Git 2.12.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I investigated a bit, I realized that at about the same time I found out about this problem, I also enabled my newly acquired WD sync synchronization and have not realized that I also added my project to the sync.
So the problem is solved, as long as I do not have my external sync service on. Which is easy to disable, but easier to forget about.

In the end I would like to share a few quick facts about my problem:

- the class duplication was being executed only when I switched windows
  (e.g. IDE to Chrome etc.)
- the duplication can (obviously) cause build fails, compilation errors, and of course can lead to invalid search results.